# Can I protect my website from client side ad injection?

Tags: javascript, security, web, ads

I recently created a [statically generated site for a friend](http://carolineletzner.com/). Today I was surprised when she emailed and said the site was riddled with ads. She has likely been the victim of ad injection. And since she was not using an unprotected network, it's likely caused by some spyware that she unintentionally installed.

Now I read [a recent report by Google](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.se/2015/05/new-research-ad-injection-economy.html) that claims that this is a big problem, 5.5% of their users had injected ads. Naturally, I don't want the users of my website to see crappy ads next to my content.

How can we stop ads from being injected on the client side? Specifically I want to stop ads being injected by viruses and web browser extensions.

If it's impossible to stop ad injection, can we at least detect ad injection and warn the user?

To clarify, I am looking for a library, API or other client side technology that let's me provide a decent protection against ad injection.

Comment: Adware installed on the computer will always have more access to the computer and thus more power than your javascript that's trying to block it, I'm not sure about extensions but "good programmed" adware will find a way to still get ad's in the user's browser.

Comment: @JameyD , yes I realize that this is a hard problem. But even though they have better access, they usually inject the ads in the DOM of my page right? Then I should be able to at least detect it and warn the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to solve this issue by your server side programming . but don't worry about it, Google Chrome, Mozilla & other browser working on this.

Google has identified and disabled 192 Chrome browser extensions that injected rogue ads into Web pages opened by users without being upfront about it. The company will scan for similar policy violations in future.

The action followed a study that the company conducted together with researchers from University of California Berkeley and which found that more than five percent of Web users who accessed Google websites had an “ad injector” installed.

The deceptive Chrome extensions were detected as part of that study, but the researchers also found ad injectors affecting browsers such as Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, on both Windows and Mac OS X.

Google doesn’t specifically ban extensions published on the Chrome Web Store from injecting ads into Web traffic, as long as they clearly inform users about what they do, but the study found that around a third of extensions with such functionality were actually malware.